# Error occurs while Running the batch file of jmeter on windows 7

Tags: jmeter

when running the batch file of jmeter(4.0 version) for windows 7 64-bit,I am getting the following error findstr is not recognized as inetrnal or external command,operable program or batch file.not able to find java executable or version
I have set the System variables also as "C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin" and also checked for java -version and JDk(9.4 version) is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [microsoft answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/findstr-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or/87f77967-538c-4a77-a9d8-917b6e577a84) you need to add to Path enviroment vatiable also `C:\Windows\System32`